# Is there a quick way to “flatten” an image in iOS

Tags: ios, photos.app, markup

I use the ‘markup’ extension in iOS Photos to ‘black out’ sensitive information in screenshots, occasionally. Unfortunately, this leaves the “revert” button, meaning that said sensitive information is sitting archived in my iCloud Photos indefinitely.

I've got the messy solution of texting myself the modified image, deleting the original, deleting it *again* from Recently Deleted Photos, and then re-saving it from the text-message I sent myself … but that's no fun.

What's the quickest way to turn a modified photo into a flattened copy of itself?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it natively is to save the photo to your **Files** (tap the **Share** icon, then scroll to **Save to Files**). Then go into the **Files** app, find the image, tap the **Share** icon there and tap **Save Image**.

This will copy the flattened file back to your Photos. Unfortunately, it looks like you lose some meta-data, but it's the best option I've found.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I've found is to use Adobe Darkroom iOS app. You can view and edit photos from your regular albums, then export them to a flat file. Export to a new file, then delete the original via Darkroom. (I just checked, and realized I've been choosing the wrong option, 'modify original' - the details there say the image is still editable...damn). I just tested and in Darkroom I see markups made in the iOS photos app.

I wish apple would make a 'flatten' option! I'd love an app that flattens all edited photos before I export to windows.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way I've found to flatten an image edited with Markup is to take a screenshot of the edited image and then crop it.